# execute apt-get install nodejs-legacy npm on git blash cmd

Tags: node.js

I was following [this tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) and I am stuck at `apt-get install nodejs-legacy npm`. How can I execute this command in git bash cmd on Windows?
I am attaching capture of my screen.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with installing `node` and `npm` using an installator from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is saying:

> In Debian based distributions, there is a name clash with another utility called node. The suggested solution is to also install the nodejs-legacy apt package, which renames node to nodejs.

So you don't need to run apt-get, this part is only for Debian users.